# which pdf library is best to use with codeigniter

Tags: tcpdf, mpdf

I would like to integrate a pdf library with codeigniter, now i use `MPDF53` library. Which would be better `MPDF` or `TCPDF`?

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF works great with CodeIgniter.  Just make a library with the TCPDF files, then you can create a controller to generate your PDFs.